# Resource file "**/*.resx" cannot be found .net core 2.1.1 angular template

Tags: angular, .net-core

I have created an SPA app in .NET Core using template angular ( ASP.NET Core with Angular).
dotnet --info provides:

[image]

The application was executing as expected. Then I added Entity Framework Core 2.1.0-preview2-final and then I started getting the below error:

[image]

The contents of my .csproj file are:

```js
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>

    <!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
    <BuildServerSideRenderer>false</BuildServerSideRenderer>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="2.1.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>



  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Could somebody explain me how to resolve this issue. My system is Mac. I am using VS Code as editor.

Comment: uninstall your package and try version 2.1.1 which is stable - see here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani Yes the error resolved after installing stable version. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

uninstall your package and try version 2.1.1 which is stable.

`uninstall-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

see here: nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore